# Problem installing package 'lxml' on mac m2 - ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml - error: legacy-install-failure

Tags: build, pip, lxml, legacy

hello i am trying to install lxml package on macbook air m2 with python 3.11 (i also tried to downgrade to 3.9) and pip 22.3.1. but i get errors that i am no able to resolve by myself nor by looking at other's question on stack overflow

Specifically I am getting this error:

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [185 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.9.13 and libxslt 1.1.35
      Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
      typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
      typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
      typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
              ^
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
      typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__int128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      creating var
      creating var/folders
      creating var/folders/94
      creating var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn
      creating var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn/T
      cc -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitdadwuuwe.c -o var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitdadwuuwe.o
      cc var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitdadwuuwe.o -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [182 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.9.13 and libxslt 1.1.35
      Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
      running install
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
      #error Unsupported architecture
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/11.0.3/include/limits.h:21:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
      typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
              ^
      note: '__uint128_t' declared here
      In file included from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10/Python.h:25:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
      In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
      #error architecture not supported
       ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      cc -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitp_h0_ggh.c -o var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitp_h0_ggh.o
      cc var/folders/94/39z5_qps5fbf5jl7pck562hc0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitp_h0_ggh.o -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I got a deprectiation warning that i resolved by installing wheel with pip3
Thanks to anyone who can help
The error is not completely printed. this is the link to the full text: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1elw9PAE1k_c3bsY0XRYuPEOQBRv1hd_lHa5aYeRDBvc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error repeatedly tells you:
#error architecture not supported

So I don't think it can be installed unfortunately.

Comment: do you think it is a problem that will be resolved once lxml supports m2?

Comment: @ManuelRech Yeah, im not sure if it will for a while though.